# Is there a .NET or Win32 version of regsvr32?

Tags: .net, installation, regsvr32

Is there a .NET or Win32 version of regsvr32? I would like to register a COM DLL with code instead of shelling out to the regsvr32 program.

Comment: I was really hoping to answer `InstallUtil`  ;)

Comment: If reg-free COM doesn't work for me, I'll probably end up writing a InstallUtil-compatible class.

Comment: InstallUtil cannot work either, you don't have the required permissions.  Not that it was designed for COM btw.

Comment: @Hans, That's not a problem as long as you run under admin mode. To get around UAC I created an installer app with the necessary UAC tags. And any program is runs inherits the needed permissions.

Comment: @Jon: that's what the OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: No... when I asked my original question I didn't mention anything about UAC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard way of registering an assembly is to call the exported `DllRegisterServer` function on the assembly.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682162(v=VS.85).aspx

In simplified terms regsvr32 essentially does the following (error checking omitted for brevity).

```
HANDLE lib = LoadLibrary(...);
FARPROC proc = GetProcAddress(lib, "DllRegisterServer");
proc();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it simply requires calling the exported function.  The devil is in the details though.  The DLL will load all its implicitly linked dependent DLLs as well.  And their DllMain() entrypoints will run.  That's kinda okay in a simple process like regsvr32, not so okay in yours that needs to survive beyond the registration step.

Then there's getting the permissions to write to the registry.  UAC will definitely put a stop to that, both for running Regsvr32 as well as calling the entrypoint directly.  To get permission from the user you will need a separate EXE with a manifest that asks for admin rights.  You're not ahead.

Look into reg-free COM, supplying the registration info in a manifest.  You then won't have to register the DLL anymore.  You'll get lots of hits if you search for the term.

Comment: My goal is an application that can install itself if you pass the right command-line switch, so I've got no problem exiting after calling DllRegisterServer. But reg-free COM sounds interesting.

Comment: Am I missing something or is reg-free COM really as simple as just setting `isolated` to true?

Comment: Afraid not, isolated applications store their DLLs in the side-by-side cache.  Similar kind of manifest hanky-panky though.

Comment: Ah, you cannot in fact use the DllRegisterServer trick, you won't have the required permissions to write to the registry.  UAC stops that.  Reg-free COM is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just load the DLL, then call it exported `DllRegisterServer()` function.